# how do you automate setting self attributes in init of python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization, subclass

I'd like to automate unpacking init variables once and for all. My thought process is to unpack all and use setattr with the name of the variable as the attribute name.

```
class BaseObject(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            setattr(self, argname, arg)

class Sub(BaseObject):
    def __init__(self, argone, argtwo, argthree, argfour):
        super(Sub, self).__init__(args*)
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
In [3]: mysubclass = Sub('hi', 'stack', 'overflow', 'peeps')

In [4]: mysubclass.argtwo
Out[4]: 'stack'
```

Based on the param for 'stack' having been named `argtwo`.

This way you'll automatically have access but you could still override like below:

```
class Sub(BaseObject):
    def __init__(self, argone, argtwo, argthree, argfour):
        super(Sub, self).__init__(arglist)
        clean_arg_three = process_arg_somehow(argthree)
        self.argthree   = clean_arg_three
```

Clearly I'm stuck on how to pass the actual name of the param (argone, argtwo, etc) as a string to `setattr`, and also how to properly pass the args into the `super init` (the `args` of `super(Sub, self).__init__(args*)`)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseObject.__init__()` needs to discover the names of the arguments to `Sub.__init__()` somehow. The explicit approach would be to pass a dictionary of arguments to `BaseObject.__init__()`, as Uri Shalit suggested. Alternatively, you can use the `inspect` module to do this magically, with no extra code in your subclass. That comes with the usual downsides of magic ("how'd that happen?").

```
import inspect

class BaseObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        frame = inspect.stack()[1][0]
        args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
        for key in args:
            setattr(self, key, values[key])

class Sub(BaseObject):
    def __init__(self, argone, argtwo, argthree, argfour):
        super(Sub, self).__init__()
```

This works fine as written, but if you don't define `Sub.__init__()`, this will grab the arguments from the wrong place (i.e., from the function where you call Sub() to create an object). You might be able to use `inspect` to doublecheck that the caller is an `__init__()` function of a subclass of `BaseObject`. Or you could just move this code to a separate method, e.g., `set_attributes_from_my_arguments()` and call that from your subclasses' `__init__()` methods when you want this behavior.

Comment: that's coldblooded, didn't expect it to get better. I'll try not to pick answers so quick

Comment: how did you know to use that portion of stack? you just use ipdb and check inspect.stack()?

Comment: I figured out part of this a few months ago when I wrote a function to dump new variables into the caller's namespace. I think I did it by trial and error with hints from the documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html. The most useful info was: (1) "[stack() returns] a list of frame records for the caller’s stack. The first entry in the returned list represents the caller; the last entry represents the outermost call on the stack." Thus stack()[1]. (2) "When [stack() returns] 'frame records,' each record is a tuple of six items: the frame object,...". Thus stack()[1][0].

Answer (score 2):

Use kwargs instead of args

```
class BaseObject(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for argname, arg in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, argname, arg)

class Sub(BaseObject):
    def __init__(self, argone, argtwo, argthree, argfour):
        super(Sub, self).__init__(argone=argone, argtwo=argtwo,   argthree=argthree)
```

Then you can do:

```
s = Sub('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import inspect

class BaseObject(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        del args['self']
        self.__dict__.update(args)

class Sub(BaseObject):
    def __init__(self, argone, argtwo, argthree, argfour):
        args = inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe()).locals
        super(Sub, self).__init__(args)

s = Sub(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: that's interesting too. why delete args['self'], I thought that was just a placeholder for it to know it is instance method?

Comment: otherwise 's.self' will be assigned. it won't break anything but it's not particularly useful. try removing 'del args['self']', you'll see that 's' and s.self' will point to the same object.

Comment: the 'if 'self' in args' condition is kinda unnecessary, I removed it